# Check statically a file existence

Tags: java, file, io

I'm wondering if exist some way to check if a file exist without create an instance of `java.io.File`

Always I have used the following way:

```
File f = new File("./path/to/file");
if (f.exists()) {
    doSomething();
}
else {
    manageError();
}
```

But know I need check some filepaths in order to create elements like a logger (with log4j), xml editor and other project structures, but I don't need work with them.

For this reason I want to know if this is possible.

I'm using J2SE-1.5_22.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see what's wrong with what you're already doing. Creating an instance of `File` isn't going to create the file on disk or anything. You could always write a static method if you want:

```
public static boolean checkFileExists(string path)
{
    return new File(path).exists();
}
```

If that doesn't satisfy your requirements, please explain what you're trying to do that doesn't work with this.

Comment: Yes, I know that my code works and its correct. The only reason for I want know this is to do shorter and more readable code. I'll use this static function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the original the authors of `java.io.File` assumed that if you're checking for a file's existence then you will probably do something with it: modify it if it exists or create a new file if it doesn't.

Jon's solution is a workaround you should probably add to your `Utils`. The `File` objects are pretty lightweight and easily discarded.

Comment: Yes. Really I go to work with them, but indirectly. In my main function I only want to check their existance and in each case, if the file exists I call a constructor with the path as parameter and the other class is which must use the File object. On the other hand, if it doesn't exist I show en error message and teminate the application. I think it would be good have a static method in `java.io.File` class for check, but the authors think other thing...

Comment: Java 7 fixes this: http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29

Comment: Wow! I just read the JavaDoc and seems that SE7 go to have a great amount of improves in this direction. They also implement a `setOwner(Path path,UserPrincipalowner)` function (I think it was necessary) and a `size()` function...Moreover this last it's also caleed statically :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would use private Java classes. Though I wouldn't suggest it, unless you know what you're doing.

Something like:

```
public static boolean fileExists(File file) {
return ((FileSystem.getFileSystem().getBooleanAttributes(file) & FileSystem.BA_EXISTS) != 0);
}
```

Though this code won't work on its own since FileSystem is a private class, but change it to a public class with reflection and it should work.